# What is it called when you shorten a word to only its important letters?

Tags: single-word-requests

ex.

> package --> pkg
>    theorem --> thm
>    proof --> pf
>    function --> fn
>    config --> cfg *(this is a bit uncommon)*
>    attribute --> attr

Example sentence:

> This process  is called _____.

Comment: I suggest that when you can find support for a particular contraction or abbreviation through publications, you can call it an abbreviation but until then, it's at best some form of slang…

Comment: Somewhat related since you mentioned shortening words to their important letters, which are usually consonants: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405088/what-do-you-call-a-word-with-vowels-removed/

Comment: We used to call that CPFese.

Comment: @HotLicks I searched CPFese online and found nothing. What does CPFese mean? As a side note, I see that you're a programmer so I will mention that yes, I am asking this somewhat in the context of computer science.

Comment: "cfg" for configuration isn't that uncommon in computing

Comment: @extremeaxe5 System/38 [Control Program Facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Program_Facility).  Can't find a command listing for S/38 online, but the one for [iSeries](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/clfinder/finder30.htm) is pretty much the same]().

Comment: @extremeaxe5 - I'm recalling that, back ca 1980, the IBM tech writers had found an academic term for the style of abbreviations, but I can't recall it.  If one dug through a bunch of tech articles from the era it might pop up, but it would be a fairly big job.

Comment: @extremeaxe5 I added a simple example sentence to hopefully avoid your question being closed. Please modify my edit as you think appropriate.

Answer (score 23):

They are called abbreviations:

[abbreviation:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/abbreviation)

> a shortened or contracted form of a word or phrase, used to represent the whole, *as Dr. for Doctor, U.S. for United States, lb. for pound.*

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

Those words are **foreshortened**, e.g.

> Morse code abbreviations are used to speed up Morse communications by **foreshortening** textual words and phrases. **Morse abbreviations are short forms representing normal textual words and phrases formed from some (fewer) characters borrowed from the words or phrases being abbreviated. [...]**
>   e.g. ctl for control
>   - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code_abbreviations

And the definition from Princeton's WordNet:

> **foreshortened**. 
>   abridge, foreshorten, abbreviate, shorten, cut, contract, reduce(verb)
>   reduce in scope while retaining essential elements
>   "The manuscript must be shortened"
>   - https://www.definitions.net/definition/foreshorten

Answer (score -1):

They’re also called acronyms when the first letters are used, such as GOP (Grand Old Party)! I was looking for this too because I always forget the word!

Answer (score -4):

**[Shorthand](https://www.infogalactic.com/info/Stenography)** or **stenography** is a style of writing / note taking that **abbreviates** words, and furthermore uses fewer strokes than usual to write the letters in the words.

Answer (score -4):

In some languages, this form of writing is the only form of **writing**.  For example, [ancient Hebrew](https://www.infogalactic.com/info/Biblical_Hebrew)'s consonants were written down, and the vowels needed to be determined from context.

Comment: Hey, this is a very useful answer. I think you probably should have made it a comment though.